# Text spliting based on special character in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a macro that could split text based on character "-". I have something like product ID made from many pieces separeted with "-". Those pieces have not always the same length but I always have the same number of them (always have four "-").

This ID is in one cell and it looks like this:

02-aaaa-mbd-98-2a.

As an output I want to have 02, aaaa, mbd, 98 and 2a in separeted cells

Comment: Text-toColumns, it is on the data tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

### Split Function as an UDF

```
Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 1)), Separator)(n - 1)
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    MsgBox "Error, verify the input data."
    EXTRACTELEMENT = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

When cell `A1` has the desired input, you use the function `=EXTRACTELEMENT($A$1;1;"-")` on cell `B1` and `=EXTRACTELEMENT($A$1;2;"-")` on cell `C1` and so on.

The result:

[image: Result 1]

### Regex

The [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pGqcDw/1) and the code for values on column A:

```
Dim str As String
Dim objMatches As Object
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    str = Cells(i, "A")
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'New regexp
    objRegExp.Pattern = "[\d\w]+?(?=\-|$)"
    objRegExp.Global = True
    Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
    If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        k = 2
        For Each m In objMatches
            Cells(i, k) = m.Value
            k = k + 1
        Next
    End If
Next i
```

The result is the same image as using an UDF.

> Remember to [enable the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128681/7690982)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30B14928-5550-41F5-97CA-7A3E9C363ED7) for help with splitting text-to-columns, if you want a macro for this, simply use "Record Macro"

Answer (score 0):

```
Split("02-aaaa-mbd-98-2a", "-") //will five you {02,aaaa,mbd,98,2a}
```

[more information here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php)